# Specialized function in a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17

I have template class. Its constructor is a template function, that calls one of two specialized functions setDescriptor(), depending on T. How can I do this?

```
// Class

template<typename T>
class Data {
public:
    Data() {}
    Data(int size);
    ~Data();

private:
    float* d;
    T descriptor;

    void setDescriptor();
};

// Constructor 

template<typename T>
Data<T>::Data(int size)
{
    d = new float[size];
    setDescriptor();
}

// Specialized functions

template<>
void Data<T1>::setDescriptor()
{
    ...
}

template<>
void Data<T2>::setDescriptor()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just call it the way you did, here's a minimal example that does that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Class

template<typename T>
class Data {
public:
    Data(int size);

private:
    T descriptor;

    void setDescriptor();
};

// Constructor

template<typename T>
Data<T>::Data(int size)
{
    setDescriptor();
}

// Specialized functions
template<>
void Data<int>::setDescriptor()
{
    cout << "int" << endl;
}

template<>
void Data<long>::setDescriptor()
{
    cout << "long" << endl;
}


int main() {
    Data<int> d(3);
    Data<long> l(3);
}
```

That will print `int` for the first constructor, and `long` for the second.

However, you have other issues in that code, like `size()`, where `size` being a parameter, it's not a callable function. And as pointed out in a comment, why not using a `vector`. If you need to use an array for some reason, don't forget the `delete` in the destructor.

Comment: I'm sorry for size(), my class is a bit more complex than this and that's a typo (that's also why i'm not using vector). Actually i'm declaring this object in another class (Data<T1> data;) and then constructing it using a function constructor. But it gives me this: error: too many arguments in function call detected during instantiation of "Data<T>::~Data() [with T=T1]"

Comment: I thought it's because of specialised functions, but as you said i'm using them in the right way.

Comment: Ok i found the error! After all this time ahah Thank's so much for your answer anyway!!